# Getting a DTMF input from phone

Tags: php, android, jquery, ivr, dtmf

I am currently developing a Jquery mobile app (IVR) with PHP/SQL backend for a college response system
My basic requirement for the app is,

1. Receive the calls to the given number automatically ,
2. Display the voice menu to the user(person who is calling to the app)
3. Receive the exam number of the student sent as DTMF input by the user
4. Send the exam result as sms to the user

My problem is point 3(receiving the DTMF input)
Is this possible ? If possible how can i achieve it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are using voice platform to run your IVR( 2 point). In that case, the 3 point will be handled by ASR ( automatic speech recognizer) of voice platform and will be passed to provided grammar of voice menu.
Let me know if i have misunderstood your question.